# Typescript: Discriminated union based on type

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union, union-types

Why is the following not possible for TS ? Why cant I use a type as discriminant ?

```
export interface A1 {
  plop: number;
}
export interface B1 {
  hop: number;
}

export interface A {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  inner: A1;
}

export interface B {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  inner: B1;
}

export type AorB = A | B;

function test(): AorB {
  let inner: A1 | B1;

  if (Math.random()) {
    inner = {plop: 4};
  } else {
    inner = {hop: 43};
  }

  return {
    foo: 42,
    bar: 'plop',
    inner
  };
}
```

The TS compiler tells me :

```
  Type '{ foo: number; bar: string; inner: A1 | B1; }' is not assignable to type 'B'.
    Types of property 'inner' are incompatible.
      Type 'A1 | B1' is not assignable to type 'B1'.
        Property 'hop' is missing in type 'A1' but required in type 'B1'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for a moment the expansion of your types. The type `AorB` represents the union:

```
{
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  inner: A1;
} | {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  inner: B1;
}
```

Noting that nowhere in this does the type `A1 | B1` appear. This is to say that the type `AorB` is expecting to have an object where the `inner` property is *known and fixed as either* `A1` *or* `B1`.

But wait? Since the properties of the enclosing object are the same (namely `foo` and `bar`), shouldn't the type above be equivalent to:

```
{
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  inner: A1 | B1;
}
```

Logically, that makes sense, you can distribute the inner union over the enclosing object type and see that you would get the same union of objects that you have for `AorB`. And in fact it [looks like this is a known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36969), but currently TypeScript isn't able to make this inference.

---

To fix this, I see a few options. First, you can just use a single interface for `AorB` where the `inner` property is given the type `A1 | B1`:

```
interface AorB {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  inner: A1 | B1;
}
```

As another option, you can modify the way in which you construct the returned object in your `test` function to clearly indicate to typescript that the resulting object has a fixed `inner` property:

```
function test2(): AorB {
  let outer = {
    foo: 42,
    bar: 'plop',
  };

  if (Math.random()) {
    // Clearly has type A
    return {
      ...outer,
      inner: {plop: 4}
    }
  } else {
    // Clearly has type B
    return {
      ...outer,
      inner: {hop: 43}
    }
  }
}
```

This way, it is obvious to the TS compiler that one branch returns type `A` and the other type `B`, which matches cleanly to the return type of `AorB`.

And finally, since we humans can see that the two types *are in fact* equivalent, you can always just ignore the error:

```
function test(): AorB {
  let inner: A1 | B1;

  if (Math.random()) {
    inner = {plop: 4};
  } else {
    inner = {hop: 43};
  }

  // @ts-ignore: This is equivalent to the type AorB after distributing the inner union...
  return {
    foo: 42,
    bar: 'plop',
    inner
  };
}
```